# Removing a subset yields different number of rows than expected

Tags: r, data.table

I have a pretty large dataset, which needs to be filtered. I would like to remove all rows, which fulfill the following condition and there are 717,329 rows in that subset. In total there are 16,198,723 rows, which thus should result in a dataset of 16,198,723 - 717,329 = 15,481,394

```
# Rows to be removed
dt[Agency == "A" & cntra_mp_id == "C" & cmsn_trd == "N", .N ]
[1] 717329
```

The issue is that actually the dataset without the subset is much smaller. I suppose the not-Operator is somehow not properly applied, correct? What's the issue here.

```
# Data.table without the rows
dt[!(Agency == "A" & cntra_mp_id == "C" & cmsn_trd == "N"), .N ]
[1] 15127505
```

Comment: instead of == try != in the condition

Comment: That would only be equivalent with an or connection, but then it also results in 15,127,505 rows with `dt[(Agency != "A" | cntra_mp_id != "C" | cmsn_trd != "N"), .N ]`

Comment: Are there NAs in your data?

Comment: check `sapply(dt, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))`

Comment: Yes, in the column `cmsn_trd` are quite some NAs and apparently, `dt[ Agency == "A" &  cntra_mp_id == "C" & is.na(cmsn_trd) , .N]
[1] 353886`, but there are now complete rows of NAs

Comment: @hannes101 `717329 + 15127505 + 353886` is nearly 16,198,723 ;  further: `NA & TRUE` is `NA` For a more detailed answer we need a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible reason might be that your columns contain `NA` values. In that case the expression `!(Agency == "A" & cntra_mp_id == "C" & cmsn_trd == "N")` will evaluate to `NA` but only those where it returns `TRUE` will be counted.

A (somewhat ugly) fix would be

`dt[
   !(Agency == "A" & cntra_mp_id == "C" & cmsn_trd == "N") |
         is.na(Agency) | is.na(cntra_mp_id) | is.na(cmsn_trd),
    .N 
   ]`